# Creating an accordion for wordpress with jquery, need help!

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm creating an accordion for wordpress and I can't seem to figure what I am doing wrong.

Ultimately I am trying to have the child elements hidden, and when the parent has been activated the child will appear.

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { //hide child page
        $('#content ul.menu ul li').hide();
        //when navigate to a child page show all pages
        $('#content ul.menu li.current-menu-item').parent("ul").show();
        //show page list when toggle
        $('#content ul.menu ul li.active ul').show();
        //show cerrent page's child page
        $('#content ul.menu ul li.current-menu-item ul').show();

        $('#content .menu ul li').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The site:  [www.svadsi.info](http://www.svadsi.info)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? Do you get errors?

Comment: Have you considered using [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement it with wordpress.

Comment: And I'm not getting any errors, I just don't think that I am targeting the classes correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress doesn't always play nice with jquery.

First you want to wrap your code in

```
$(function() {
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

Also, I would recommend using

```
.addClass('hidden');
```

and

```
removeClass('hidden');
```

instead of .hide(); and .show(); when dealing with the same problem.

Please feel free to follow up with comments and I'll help you troubleshoot.

Comment: indeed, but for some reason i've gotten wordpress to work with one and not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain you problem more please.

You should caught the click event on li cause it bubble

```
    $('#content .menu ul li').click(function(e) {
        $(e).stopPropagation();
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```